# GPIO Raspberry Pi pin maintain last status when interrupt script and restart it

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, mqtt, gpio

I am working with MQTT and GPIO, and i have noticed that the pin maintain the last status like a memory, i make an example this is my script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

#required libraries
import sys                                 
import ssl
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
import RPi.GPIO as gpio
import json
from time import sleep

try:

    ledPin = 25
    gpio.setmode(gpio.BCM)
    gpio.setup(ledPin, gpio.OUT)

    def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
        print("Connected with result code "+str(rc))
        client.subscribe("topic/led_switch",1)

    def on_message(client, userdata, msg):

        json_data = msg.payload.decode('utf-8')

        print("Message received: "+json_data)

        parsed_json = json.loads(json_data)

        if "on" in parsed_json:
            gpio.output(ledPin, gpio.HIGH)
        elif "off" in parsed_json:
            gpio.output(ledPin, gpio.LOW)


    def on_subscribe(mqttc, obj, mid, granted_qos):
        print("Subscribed: "+str(mid)+" "+str(granted_qos)+"data"+str(obj))


    mqttc = mqtt.Client(client_id="RaspberryPi_Sub", clean_session=True)

    mqttc.on_connect = on_connect
    mqttc.on_message = on_message
    mqttc.on_subscribe = on_subscribe



    mqttc.connect("...my_server", port=8883)

    mqttc.loop_forever()

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass
finally:
    gpio.cleanup()
```

if i stop the script with CTRL+C and the led was for example HIGH, when i start the script again the LED start HIGH, but it should start from LOW state, viceversa if i stop when is LOW, then restart LOW, any idea?

Comment: Why do you think this is MQTT related? Or are you seeing an incoming message on start up? e.g. are you publishing the control message "retained"?

Comment: I have tried to comment the subscribe line, and when i start the script and the led was on start on

Comment: If you start the script but do not publish any control messages do you still see a log message like "Message received:..."?

Comment: Yes, the GPIO keeps it's state. That's how it works. If you need it in a special state on startup, you have to set it to it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the client to effectively remember the last state when it is restarted then you should publish the control messages with the *retained* flag set to true.

This will mean that the broker will deliver the last published message to the client when it subscribes.

This is something that needs to be set in the publishing client, not the subscriber.